# imagecreatefromjpeg() - Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I can't upload image with codeigniter and get following error.

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>  Severity: Warning
>  Message:
>   imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Invalid
>   SOS parameters for sequential JPEG
>  Filename:
>   libraries/Image_lib.php
>  Line Number: 1455
>
> **A PHP Error was
>   encountered**
>  Severity: Warning
>  Message: imagecreatefromjpeg():
>   '/home/gsgsadh/public_html/uploads/a31d12f51b36659f5456e2530237e779.jpg'
>   is not a valid JPEG file
>  Filename: libraries/Image_lib.php
>   Line Number: 1455

function `image_create_gd` at **application/libraries/MY_Image_lib.php**

```
public function image_create_gd($path = '', $image_type = '')
{
    if ($path === '')
    {
        $path = $this->full_src_path;
    }

    if ($image_type === '')
    {
        $image_type = $this->image_type;
    }

    switch ($image_type)
    {
        case 1:
            if ( ! function_exists('imagecreatefromgif'))
            {
                $this->set_error(array('imglib_unsupported_imagecreate', 'imglib_gif_not_supported'));
                return FALSE;
            }

            return imagecreatefromgif($path);
        case 2:
            if ( ! function_exists('imagecreatefromjpeg'))
            {
                $this->set_error(array('imglib_unsupported_imagecreate', 'imglib_jpg_not_supported'));
                return FALSE;
            }

/*No.1455*/  return imagecreatefromjpeg($path); //****Line number is 1455****
        case 3:
            if ( ! function_exists('imagecreatefrompng'))
            {
                $this->set_error(array('imglib_unsupported_imagecreate', 'imglib_png_not_supported'));
                return FALSE;
            }

            return imagecreatefrompng($path);
        default:
            $this->set_error(array('imglib_unsupported_imagecreate'));
            return FALSE;
    }
}
```

what's the solution? How to change the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set PHP to ignore jpeg warnings

```
ini_set ('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);
```

on the line just before invoking imagecreatefromjpeg()